# What are the options for setting reports caching in VS 2008 R2 when previewing?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've been creating a few reports within VS 2008 R2 that pass a few parameters to a database function and when running these I noticed that sometimes it wasn't bringing back what was expected when previewing them. This lead me to research whether the datasets / datasources were being cached between iterations of previewing.

I discovered that caching occurs (main source of info for me was [here](http://sqlblog.de/blog/2008/12/ssrs-disable-reporting-services-cache-in-preview-mode/).

As per this document and some others it shows how to disable caching in preview mode using the RSReportDesigner.config file and the 'CacheDataForPreview' entry, but what I want to know is, are there any other ways of manipulating this caching? For example, rather than disable it could I change the session timing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend BIDS Helper. It is a a free add-on to BIDS/SSDT that provides great extra functionality, such as being able to [delete dataset cache files](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Delete%20Dataset%20Cache%20Files&referringTitle=Documentation) in SSRS. You can download it from [Codeplex](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/). This way caching is not completely disabled and you can choose when to delete the cache.

Comment: Thanks for info. I've not had a chance to play with it yet but having read up on it I think it will do the trick.